# Mouse Hovering was Required for my Jbutton with pic to be visible

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, mousehover

Mouse Hovering was Required for my Jbutton with pic to be visible, I didn't @Override my paint function anywhere.How to display all the buttons with images without the need of mouse hovering ?!

[before Mouse hovering pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn6x3.png)

[After mouse hovering on all Jbuttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEDLj.png)

```
public class JPicButton extends JButton {
int x, y, max;

/**
 * @param path
 *            :"resources/graphics/index.jpg"
 */
public JPicButton(String fileName, int max) {
    this.max = max;
    try {
        // ImageIcon mx = new ImageIcon(JPicButton.class.getResource("/graphics/" +
        // fileName)); #works
        Image img = ImageIO.read(JPicButton.class.getResource("/graphics/" + fileName));
        img = img.getScaledInstance(10 * (40 / max), 10 * (45 / max), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon mc = new ImageIcon(img);
        this.setIcon(mc);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public JPicButton() {

}

public void setOrigin(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void setPath(String fileName) {
    try {
        Image img = ImageIO.read(JPicButton.class.getResource("/graphics/" + fileName));
        img = img.getScaledInstance(10 * (40 / max), 10 * (45 / max), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon mc = new ImageIcon(img);
        this.setIcon(mc);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * @return the x
 */
public synchronized int getX() {
    return x;
}

/**
 * @return the y
 */
public synchronized int getY() {
    return y;
} }
```

this button is initialized in the constructor of the Jpanel too as

```
package Gui;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
 import java.awt.Font;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public class GamePage extends JPanel {
JPicButton groundMatrix[][];
int xMax, yMax;

public GamePage() {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setVisible(false);

    setLayout(null);
    setSize(700, 500);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("MineSweeper");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(48, 13, 250, 50);
    add(lblNewLabel);
    lblNewLabel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    lblNewLabel.setOpaque(true);
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    JPanel game = new JPanel();
    game.setBounds(50, 80, 600, 400);
    add(game);
    game.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("");
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(342, 15, 66, 50);
    add(lblNewLabel_1);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    label.setBounds(584, 13, 66, 50);
    add(label);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Reset");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(446, 15, 97, 50);
    add(btnNewButton);

    xMax = 15;
    yMax = 10;
    int Width = 40;
    groundMatrix = new JPicButton[xMax][yMax];

    for (int y = 0; y < yMax; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < xMax; x++) {
            groundMatrix[x][y] = new JPicButton("Layout1d.jpg", 10);
            groundMatrix[x][y].setLocation(Width * x, Width * y);
            groundMatrix[x][y].setSize(Width, Width);
            game.add(groundMatrix[x][y]);
            groundMatrix[x][y].setOrigin(x, y);

        }

    }

    // GridBagConstraints mineGround = new GridBagConstraints();
    // mineGround.gridheight = 45;
    // mineGround.gridwidth = 40;

}

/**
 * @return the groundMatrix
 */
public synchronized JPicButton[][] getGroundMatrix() {
    return groundMatrix;
}

/**
 * @param groundMatrix
 *            the groundMatrix to set
 */
public synchronized void setGroundMatrix(JPicButton[][] groundMatrix) {
    this.groundMatrix = groundMatrix;
}

/**
 * @return the xMax
 */
public synchronized int getxMax() {
    return xMax;
}

/**
 * @return the yMax
 */
public synchronized int getyMax() {
    return yMax;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame js = new JFrame();
    GamePage gd = new GamePage();
    gd.setVisible(true);
    js.add(gd);
    js.pack();
    js.setSize(700, 500);
    js.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

for full code visit 
https://bitbucket.org/sarjuns/minesweeper/src

Comment: Is this a question? Or are you making a statement? If you want to explain how something works, that is fine. But, to that you should ask a clear question. Then, answer the question your self.

Comment: sorry I edited my question.

Comment: You've overridden `paint` on some other parent component? You've made the parent container visible before adding the buttons?  You've failed to call `revalidate` and `repaint` when dynamically updating the UI. We can keep guessing or you could provide a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can stop wasting each other time

Comment: Don't override the `x/y` positions of the buttons, they are already properties of the button and doing so could have adverse effects and how the button is displayed

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry I'm a beginner. I don't know how to modify my code according to what you have said. not a helpful comment

Comment: @ARJUN Might not be helpful to you, but it would be extraordinarily  helpful to us, because all you've left us with is guess work, which is just going to be waste of each others time. Linking to external repositories is generally discouraged as it provides little or no benefit to others nor does it provide context for others to determine the usefulness of the suggestions provided

Comment: So you're telling me to post the entire code ? Or what else should i do ?

Comment: @ARJUN No, I'm asking you to distill your code down to a runnable example which demonstrates the problem you are having in a way which represents the structure you are using

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have edited my code to a runnable version without the graphics, there is a main in the GamePage !!

Comment: @ARJUN  ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Observations (tl;dr)

Having walked through your code, there are a number of issues which are likely compounding together to cause all sorts of issues, if not immediately, then into the future (and as the solution becomes more complex).

### Reliance of `null` layouts

Every where I look in your code I see `setLayout(null);`.  This is going to haunt you, especially as you try and run the code on different platforms

Swing, like most decent UI frameworks, has an inbuilt concept of how components should be laid out in a platform independent manner.

I'd highly recommend taking some time to look over [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Looking through your code I can find good places to use `BorderLayout`, `GridBagLayout`, `GridLayout` and `CardLayout`, all of which would greatly reduce the complexity of the code and make it easier to change (should you have to) and maintain, as well as support different platforms and rendering pipelines.

### Using the `JLayeredPane` of `JFrame`

`getLayeredPane().add(gamepage);` ... I'm not sure what benefit you thought this was going to provide, but it's a very uncommon solution.  The `JLayeredPane` is a great way to display "popup" style information to the user or provide "overlay" information over the content pane, but that's me.

## The core of the problem

In the `JPicButton` class you implement two methods..

```
/**
 * @return the x
 */
public synchronized int getX() {
    return x;
}

/**
 * @return the y
 */
public synchronized int getY() {
    return y;
}
```

The problem is, these two methods are already defined by `JButton` and relate to the location the button should be placed relative to it's parent container.  Overriding these methods means that when you use `setLocation`, the values are been ignored.

So, when I modify your code to remove those methods, I get the following result...

[image: Finally laid out]

The "x/y" position you are trying to manage should actually be managed by a model, the GUI should simply be a representation of the state of the model.

## Final Remarks

I've made a number of remarks about the state of your code, it would unprofessional for me to do otherwise, as you are digging yourself into a never ending hole of re-work and head scratching issues which could be easily solved with the available API support.

I believe, however, you've made a good start on attempting to solve the over all problem and would encourage you to continue, but taking into account some of the observations that have been made.

Comment: I have tried the contentpane, Instead of layeredpane it shows me different view if i run it again 
but this for another page with background color

Thanks I appreciate the help for figuring out the issue on setX/setY

Comment: Short answer is, you can't use `set/getX/Y` of the `JButton` this way, you need to find a different way to store this information - which is where the model comes in.